# Correct way to deep clone recursive object in React (normalized state)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, normalizr

I'm building an app where I end with normalized state. It then builds HTML based on `content` property. The idea is that sections can have children that are referring to other elements in the `elements`.

```
this.state = {
        elements: {
                byId : {
                1: {
                    content: 'Section',
                    children: [2, 3]
                },
                2: {
                    content: 'Child section'
                },
                3: {
                    content: 'Child section',
                    children: [4]

                },
                4: {
                    content: '2nd level-child section'
                }
            }
        },
        content: [1]
    }
    
    clone() {
       ???
    };
```

Adding, removing, is pretty straightforward. I need to have a functionality to clone an element and it's children. So e.g. if I I'd like to clone 1st section it needs to create new elements and update all `ids` in new section.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Or is this structure won't work for that kind of job?

## Desired state upon cloning

```
this.state = {
    elements: {
        byId: {
            1: {
                content: 'Section',
                children: [2, 3]
            },
            2: {
                content: 'Child section'
            },
            3: {
                content: 'Child section',
                children: [4]

            },
            4: {
                content: '2nd level-child section'
            },

            // new elements
            5: {
                content: 'Section copy',
                children: [6, 7] // updated ids
            },
            6: {
                content: 'Child section copy'
            },
            7: {
                content: 'Child section copy',
                children: [8] //updated ids

            },
            8: {
                content: '2nd level-child section copy'
            },
        }
    },
    content: [1, 5] // updated content
}
```

Comment: correct way? what way you've tried yet so far?

Comment: My current way is cumbersome and doesn't allow to have children up to third level. I'd appreciate if someone could create a recursive function that allows for any children depth

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep

Comment: @JoeyGough I understand that I need clonedeep, my question is rather how to update ids

Comment: but in your example you are adding ids. I do not see any update. `var obj = {}; obj["8"] = "hello world"`. that would be how you add key value pairs to an Object

Comment: @JoeyGough adding to `elements` is pretty easy. My struggle is to update `children` with newly created `ids`. E.g. section 5 now has children of 6, 7 and so on.

Comment: it is not clear what logic you are trying to implement. in the function you could deep copy this.state.elements, edit the object as you like and then this.setState({elements: deepcopiedAndEditedObject}). Maybe it would be better to have you elements object as an array?

Comment: @JoeyGough, yes so question is basically about how to update and edit this new copied object :)